# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - MVC 4 with IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

This seems like a question that has already been asked/answered many times. Its not.

**Development Environment:**
VS 2012 and MVC 4. I am using the built in IIS Express to run the app.

This error was not occurring until yesterday. It suddenly began to occur and I am stuck. Its strange that It occurs only in ONE scenario.

When I try to access `http://localhost:49962/managescholars/`, it shows me the error

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

But using `http://localhost:49962/managescholars/Index` works fine. Other action methods of same controller also work fine. such as `http://localhost:49962/managescholars/create`. All other controllers work fine as well.

I have tried adding the following to web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <handlers/>
</system.webServer>
```

I also have tried running the following command as administrator

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

But none of them worked.

**Edit:**

I have modified my routes. They look as follows.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ManageScholarLectures",
            url: "Manage/Lectures/{userFriendlyName}",
            defaults: new { controller = MVC.ManageLectures.Name , 
                            action = MVC.ManageLectures.ActionNames.Index, 
                            userFriendlyName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ManageScholarEdit",
            url: "Manage/Scholars/{userFriendlyName}",
            defaults: new { controller = MVC.ManageScholars.Name, 
                            action = MVC.ManageScholars.ActionNames.Edit }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, 
                            action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index, 
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I am using `T4MVC` template.

It still does not work even if I leave the default route at the bottom and remove the first two routes. What have I done wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you change something in your routes recently?  That would be the first place I would look.

Comment: The routes should default just a controller URL to it's index page unless you changed it

Comment: Yes. you are right. I have modified my routes recently. I have edited my question and have included RegisterRoutes method

Comment: I ran into this problem because I had a folder in the root of my MVC project that had the same name as an area. The accepted answer fixed this issue as well.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your routes seems fine. This should not cause any problem. The error is occuring only on `http://localhost:49962/managescholars/` which means that there might be some other resource with same name. 
Can you make sure your code does not mistakenly creates a folder **managescholars** during execution?"

Comment: Thank you very much. This was indeed the problem. I had mistakenly written a code which would save a file and would create a folder. This created "managescholars" which was causing the issue.

Comment: Perfect answer, had same problems with "/products" routing, and yes, I had a physical folder and a controller called "products", deleted folder and bingo! thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes!  Physical folder was my problem too.

Comment: When using Server.MapPath(.....), it will use the routing path as folders (area name, and so on), and if you create a folder, it will create it starting from the root path of your website, this might cause a problem in routing...

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem. To solve is very easy.

This problem occurs because of an IIS Express conflict when you edit the properties in the Protect URL in the Project settings.
To solve this problem is very easy:

1 - Look for the file "applicationhost.config" in the ".vs \ config" directory. This folder is at the root of the solution. You can open it using Notepad ++

2 - Search for the name of your control using 'find' of your program (Ctrl + F). In my case, the control that gave problem was the 'Offices'.

3 - Delete any node where you place the IIS settings for such a URL. See example below:

```html
    <site name="G4.Admin(1)" id="8">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projetos\PortalG4\src\G4.Admin" />
                    <virtualDirectory path="/Offices/Edit" physicalPath="C:\Projetos\PortalG4\src" />
                    <virtualDirectory path="/Offices" physicalPath="C:\Projetos\PortalG4" />
                </application>
                <application path="/Offices/Edit/2" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projetos\PortalG4\src\G4.Admin" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6920:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

You should delete every element

```
<site name = "NAME_PROJECT" id = "X">
```

Note: Make a backup of the file before making the changes.

Hugs

Comment: Correct!, This is what's happening most of the time and because of that you will get forbidden error.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the great instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm assuming that

```
 http://localhost:49962/managescholars/
```

is in fact

```
 http://localhost:49962/manage/scholars/
```

. If not there's your problem :)

I'm not an expert on routes, but in your route for `Scholars` the `userFriendlyName` param is not optional which means that `http://localhost:49962/manage/scholars/` won't match any of your rules and IIS will treat it a request to list the content of the folder.

Comment: I would rather state that `http://localhost:49962/scholars/manage is the right REST-like url 

Answer (score 1):

Great !!
In my case it was because I configured the application to run in a wrong url, but when I returned to the correct one, the look did not overwhelm the applicationhost.config.

As I said above, I only managed to solve those steps.

Comment: You could just have edited your other answer and added this instead of making a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with Visual Studio 2015, I solved the problem with the following steps:

- Stop IIS Express
- Close Visual studio
- Delete file applicationhost.config in {my solution directory}.vs\config
- Delete directory Documents\IISExpress\config
- Start VS, F5 and enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone get the same problem I got and enter this page deseperatly.
If debugging website works but not on one website :

Check modification on global.asax
Check if the route configuration is still present...

I know it's dumb but lost 6 hours after a git merge...

Answer (score 0):

I know original question is answered but below worked in my case.
I got exact same issue on VS2013 using IIS Express. In my case visiting /Login was not getting Index action in LoginController. There was no physical folder when I checked but after more digging I found there was virtual directory created on IIS Express for /Login path which caused this. I deleted the virtual directory from applicationhost config(Documents\IISExpress\config) to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after using @Fl4v answer, I search for **directoryBrowse** attribute on file applicationhost.config in {my solution directory}.vs\config and there was false. 
Changed to true, restart iis and now it finnally works.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Go the username/ and enable it if not enable.