# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction not redirecting to Index of another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

In my Account/Login controller method, I have something like:

```
var classA = GetObject(); //actual code omitted
switch(classA.PropA)
{
    case 1:
        return RedirectToAction("Action2", "Registration");
    //more case code omitted
    default:
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Registration");
}
```

All the cases work fine in the switch block except the default where it's suppose to go to Index in RegistrationController. Instead of that, it takes me to localhost:port/Registration, where the action Index is omitted.

It works fine if the ActionName is changed to something else - Index2 for example. Also works fine if the controller name is changed to something else.

RouteConfig is 
just the auto-generated code from creating the project, which is as follows:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
     }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when `RedirectToAction("Index", "Registration");` executes?

Comment: Sorry I did forget to mention that. It just goes to localhost:port/Registration instead

Comment: Did you put debugger on Index action method?

Comment: It's not stepping into Registration/Index at all

Comment: and if you enter  `localhost:port/Registration/index` then?

Comment: Manually entering the URL on browser works absolutely fine

Comment: can you share RouteConfig

Comment: Shared. Also added the details you asked me for previous into the description

Comment: @ChenChen according to your route it should work and what error are you getting with localhost:port/Registration/ ?

Comment: @Usman HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the route setting the reason it does not include `Index` in the `URL` because according to `default route`

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

when you enter `/Registration` the route already knows the default action which is `index` so it does not add `/index` in `URL` and about

> 403.14 forbidden

if you look at this post [HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - MVC 4 with IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297490/http-error-403-14-forbidden-mvc-4-with-iis-express) it could be because you might have a file or folder named `Registration` in the project directory

Comment: This is absolutely spot on! Thanks!

Comment: @ChenChen you can accept my answer if it helped :) if you dont know how you can check this  [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @ChenChen no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `RedirectionToAction("Index","ControllerName");`
it will redirect you with the default mapping config to `localhost:port/ControllerName`
and in your case if you execute the `RedirectionToAction("Index","ControllerName");` it will redirect you to 
`localhost:port/Registration`

Comment: This clears things up a lot. Thanks. However, is "Registration" a reserved word or something? As i'm getting "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory" with that controller, but not with any other controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use on

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and in RouteConfig you can route Action "Index" to Controller "Registration"

like

```
routes.MapRoute("Index", "Index", new { controller = "Registration", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: You should also verify this code in RouteConfig.                                                                            routes.MapRoute("Registration", "Registration/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Registration", Action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });